# NSDate from NSDateComponent short by 1 hour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When trying to specify a date (i.e. a birthday) using NSDateComponent I realised that the date I was getting back was 1 hour short.

```
NSDateComponents *birthdayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[birthdayComponents setDay:5];
[birthdayComponents setMonth:3];
[birthdayComponents setYear:1968];

NSDate *birthday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:birthdayComponents];
NSLog(@"BIRTHDAY: %@", birthday);
[birthdayComponents release];
```

.

```
OUTPUT: "BIRTHDAY: 1968-03-04 23:00:00 +0000"
```

I can correct this by adding:

```
[birthdayComponents setHour:1];
```

but was curious why just setting **5, 3, 1968** did not give **1968-03-05 00:00:00 +0000**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set the timeZone property of birthdayComponents, so it defaults to UTC. When you create a date from it, the date components are translated to your local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

What is your current timezone?  ;)

Your output when you log the date is showing the time in GMT, you are probably creating it in your time zone, which is one hour off of GMT.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues due to daylight savings - was getting 0400 vs 0500, etc.  I resolved this by setting the timezone and locale.

```
// set the locale (for date calculations)
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_US"] autorelease];
endDate.locale = locale;
```